# XML for User Interface Definition

Tags: xml, user-interface, cross-platform, xul, xforms

I'm looking for information to choose a XML for User Interface Definition to build UI in new project. The project's objective is running in both web and desktop environments and support cross-platform. Therefore I focus on XUL and XForms but I'm not familiar with the XForms. Please give me some advices, what are cons and pros and the future of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org). Choosing a good XML format is only part of the battle. You then need to turn that XML into a functioning UI. Metawidget takes care of that (for many platforms), as well as letting you plug in your own XML format as desired.

Here's an example of plugging in XML Schema as a format: http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2013/03/xml-schema-wsdl-and-soap-ui-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go with MXML (Adobe Flex). It could be both a flash (browser) and air application (desktop).

Answer (score 0):

XForms is more and more popular now because there are cross-browser implementations such as XSLTForms and Ubiquity XForms which don't require to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid XUL since it's Firefox-only and is [going to be dropped for Firefox 4.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546857).

Comment: Thank for the information. I'm still learning about XForms but it seems to work with web environment only. I've found Apogée, a SWT XForms engine, but still being developed. So which engine can dynamically generate the desktop forms GUI and validate data?

Comment: HTML would work too.  It works on the web, and on the desktop (by either using local pages, or running it inside xulrunner).

Comment: To be clear, *remote* (web-delivered) XUL support is being dropped, which has basically not been supported for a long time.  Firefox is BUILT using XUL, so it most certainly is not being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retain the "web" portion of your project, and if by that you mean that it runs in any browser, XUL is not an option.  You can use it as a Firefox extension, or you can build a stand-alone application (not running in a browser) with XUL, but it is not a technology for building a UI across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Find a full comprehensive introduction with lot's of external links from [here](http://xml.coverpages.org/userInterfaceXML.html). Including:

- XUL (by Mozilla)
- XAML (by Microsoft)
- XForms (by W3C)
- etc.

Also as far as I remember, JavaFx has close ties to XML based UI definition. Also QML is a markup based UI definition language for Qt which is used by many projects such as Ubuntu. In Gnome realm you can use Glade (opensource software) to create an XML file from your drag-n-drop created UIs, which is then used by many libraries to reconstruct intended UI at runtime.